# Reflected XSS in form action - form action best practice

Tags: php, html, forms, xss

I have just received a report of a failed PCI compliance scan due to Reflected XSS in a php / IIS web application that I am responsible for.

Exploitable sample :

```
GET /login/recover/en?alert('TK00000105') HTTP/1.1
```

Evidence :

```
<form id='recover_form_1' method='post'  action='https://www.somebody.com/login/recover/en?alert('TK00000105')' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

The output is generated by a form class, which has recently gained the feature of providing a full action if one was not provided (JavaScript enhancements, and HTML5 validation).  This action is the full URL (more or less) including the query string.  Often the query string is in fact a dictating factor to the actual page loaded (it's not all friendly!), so I would not be able to just blindly cut the query from the URL.

How should I (How do you), sanitize url's for form actions, what are the actual dangerous vectors that should be filtered?

Would it be sufficient to strip html tags, or is the only real way to patch this up to make every use of the form provide a specific action?

------------------ Edit  Details of Form Creation -------------------------

The construction and opening form tag is generated as follows :

```
public function __construct( $id = false, $method = 'post', $action = '', $class= '')
    {        
        $this->_method = strtolower($method);
        $this->_action = $action;
        $this->_class =  $class;

        if ($id == false) 
        {
            FormEX::$_numForms++;
            $this->_id = 'form_'.FormEX::$_numForms."";
        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->_id = $id;
        }

        FormEX::Persist($this);
        $this->Controls = new \Collection(__NAMESPACE__.'\HTMLControl');
    }

...

     public function StartForm()
        {
            $action = $this->_action != '' ? $this->_action : $this->GenerateAction();
            $class = $this->_class != '' ? " class ='{$this->_class}'" : '';
            $enc = $this->_formEnctype != '' ? $this->_formEnctype : 'multipart/form-data';
            return "<form id='{$this->getID()}' method='{$this->_method}' $class action='$action' enctype='$enc'>";
        }
```

You would create the form in a controller (or elsewhere behind the view)  and use in the view something like the following :

```
<?if($this->form != null): ?>
    <?= $this->form->StartForm(); ?>
    <fieldset id="<?= $this->form->getID(); ?>">
        <div class='input'>
            <?= $this->form->_rc('Confirm'); ?>
            <?= $this->form->_rc('Cancel'); ?>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->form->EndForm(); ?>
<?endif ?>
```

--------------------- Edit  -  Thanks Marek -------------------------------

So one improvement would be to ensure that the url is encoded and at the same time defensively encode all of the developer writable attributes at the point of output.

_s() is an encoding shortcut for `htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')` in our library.

```
public function StartForm()
{
    $action = $this->_action != '' ? $this->_action : $this->GenerateAction();
    $class = $this->_class != '' ? " class ='{$this->_class}'" : '';
    $enc = $this->_formEnctype != '' ? $this->_formEnctype : 'multipart/form-data';
    $formTag = "<form id='" . _s($this->getID()) . "' method='" . _s($this->_method) . "' $class action='" . _s($action) . "' enctype='" . _s($enc) . "'>";
    return $formTag;
}
```

---

With regards to my question, is there anything else that I should be aware of?

Thanks.

Comment: How is the form tag created? Is it fully handled by the library? Or only the action attribute is retrieved from it?

Comment: @Marek Fully handled by the library,  so within a template the developer would use $myForm->Start()  which would output the opening tag in full including the action (either provided in constructor or generated automaticaly)

Comment: You are done now (provided you use utf8). The form library now allows to pass even unsanited user input in a safe way. So it still means you have to later handle the would be javascript from query string later, but how to do it, it's up to you. I would probably just quitely discard the request if the user is not found in DB, using parameter binding, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library is exploitable, it doesn't properly escape single quotes, which it uses to quote attributes. `htmlspecialchars` doesn't escape single quotes with default parameters (I hope the library uses it). The form tag should be one of these:

```
<form id='recover_form_1' method='post'  action='https://www.somebody.com/login/recover/en?alert(&#039;TK00000105&#039;)' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

<form id="recover_form_1" method="post"  action="https://www.somebody.com/login/recover/en?alert('TK00000105')" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

First one adds `ENT_QUOTES` flag to htmlspecialchars, the second uses double quotes, and leaves singles as is.

You should now fix the library and notify the developers.

Comment: Great Marek thanks for the solution and the clarity.  I wonder if you know of any other situations that should be accounted for, or does this conclude the safety of the action?

Comment: I would use htmlspecialchars in StartForm(), that way you also escape supplied $action parameter. Simply escape everything that comes from outside of the class, this includes $id, $class, $method ($this->_formEnctype seems to be autodetected?).

Comment: $this->_formEnctype can be overridden by a setter so should be encoded also.  Quite right by the way, thanks.